# Get properties file from external path in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, properties

I'm trying to add internationalization to my Java webApp (I'm using Spring & Maven).
I need to get the properties file both from the jsp:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="locale.language" />
```

and the JavaScript file, using JQuery library :jquery.i18n.properties.

The problem is: setBundle needs file to be put in src/main/resources path;
instead the JQuery plugin needs file to be put in src/main/webapp path.

How could I avoid the duplication of these properties file?